# Sending single unsinged int to VBO

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to send a single unsigned int to vbo, but when I test its value in the vertex shader (which should be 1), the value is different from the one expected.

The variable that contains my unsigned ints is textureIds

The code that load the vbo :

```
std::vector<unsigned int> textureIds;
glGenBuffers(1, &vboID_m);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID_m);
{
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            (vertices.size() + texture.size() + normals.size())
                    * sizeof(float) + textureIds.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), 0,
            GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(float),
            vertices.data());
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float),
            texture.size() * sizeof(float), texture.data());
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            (vertices.size() + texture.size()) * sizeof(float),
            normals.size() * sizeof(float), normals.data());
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            (vertices.size() + texture.size() + normals.size()) * sizeof(float),
            textureIds.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), textureIds.data());
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

The code that draw the vbo:

```
void Chunck::draw() const {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID_m);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float),
            BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float),
            BUFFER_OFFSET(verticeSize_m * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float),
            BUFFER_OFFSET(
                    (verticeSize_m + textureSize_m) * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(unsigned int),
                BUFFER_OFFSET(
                        (verticeSize_m + textureSize_m + normalSize_m) * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassTexture_m.getID());

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dirtTexture_m.getID());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, verticeSize_m / 3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 in_Vertex;
in vec2 in_TexCoord0;
in vec3 in_normal;

in int in_textureId;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;

out vec2 coordTexture;
out vec3 normal;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 rayDir;

out float grassAmount;
out float dirtAmount;


void main()
{
    vec4 pos = model * vec4(in_Vertex, 1.0);
    vec2 mu = vec2(0., 0.);
    //pos.y = max(pos.y, 10 * exp(-((pos.x - mu.x) * (pos.x - mu.x) + (pos.z - mu.y) * (pos.z - mu.y)) / 100.));

    gl_Position = projection * view * pos;
    FragPos = vec3(pos);
    coordTexture = in_TexCoord0;
    normal = in_normal;
    rayDir = (view * model * vec4(FragPos, 1.)).xyz;

    grassAmount = 0;
    dirtAmount = 0;

    if (in_textureId == 0)
        grassAmount = 1;
    else if (in_textureId == 1)
        dirtAmount = 1;
}
```

I should enter into the second if, but it doesn't :\

Comment: You have to use [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) focus on **`I`**

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Where do you set `in_textureId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `glVertexAttribIPointer` (focus on **`I`**), when defining the array of generic vertex attribute data, for the vertex attribute `in int in_textureId;`.
Vertex attribute data defined by `glVertexAttribPointer` will be converted to floating point.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 10.2. CURRENT VERTEX ATTRIBUTE VALUES; page 344](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> The **`VertexAttribI*`** commands specify signed or unsigned fixed-point **values
>   that are stored as signed or unsigned integers**, respectively. Such values are referred to as pure integers.
>
> ...
>
> All other **`VertexAttrib*`** commands specify values that are **converted directly to the internal floating-point representation**.

---

Note, you should use either [Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index) to specify the attribute index in the vertex shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_Vertex;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 in_TexCoord0;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 in_normal;
layout(location = 3) in int in_textureId;
```

or you should ask for the attribute index by [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) aftet the program has been linked:

e.g.:

```
GLuint progObj = ...;
glLinkProgram( progObj );

GLint texIdInx = glGetAttribLocation( progObj, "in_textureId" );
```

```
glVertexAttribIPointer(
    texIdInx, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(unsigned int),
    BUFFER_OFFSET((verticeSize_m + textureSize_m + normalSize_m) * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texIdInx );
```

**Edit**:

Of course, [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml) is a proper solution too.

Comment: Many thanks !!! It does the trick, But I still dont get why you have to specify the type for glVertexAttribPointer as whatever it will convert the value to a float :\

Comment: I use glBindAttribLocation ;)